# need help property window way zoomed out on ui

Tags: interface, customization

Not really a 3d question but I pressed a button and..[image] the property window is zoomed out a ton how can I get it back to normal I do not know what button I pressed. I have tried middle mouse button I could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover your mouse over the panel for which you want to change the size of the UI (in your case the properties panel), hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press down <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd>. Move the mouse up and down to resize the content.

If you want to set the panel back to default size, hover mouse over it and press <kbd>Home</kbd>

Comment: Plus and minus when pressed over a panel region has same effect